# java and access error when connecting to the database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, vpn

Today I encountered the following problem. When connecting to a database, the following error.Appeal to the remote database by connecting through vpn.

1. Added necessary firewall ports and even tried to disconnect its(did not help)
2. Added record to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.policy 
   grant codeBase "file:/-" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
   };(did not help)
3. If trying to connect with same data through sql management studio, it works and there    is access. from the development environment no connection
   Example(string connection = jdbc:sqlserver://DEVMSSQL14.test.com:1433;SCHEMA=test;DATABASENAME=test, sql managment studia = DEVMSSQL14.test.com,1433)
4. on another computer it works without problems, the same version of the project

It remains only to "Permission denied: connect".Maybe somebody faced with similar

Error:

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host DEVMSSQL14.test.com, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Permission denied: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error message, you have shown like DEVMSSQL14.`test`.com, 1433 has failed.
I believe, it is correct. I dont think. this host name is correct. which says "TEST" as domain

Open the `cmd`, try to ping `DEVMSSQL14.test.com`

Success case :
If you are able to ping, then make sure the services are running for sql in services
Failure case: 
Get the right host name to establish the connection

When i tried, i got this message, because i may be out of network.

```
Pinging DEVMSSQL14.test.com [208.64.121.161] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.

Request timed out.
```

Comment: Please see paragraph 3 and 4. There I tell about connection to the sql server using sql management studio and the possibility of the program  execute correctly on other computers. sql server pings and no packet loss. Maybe problem in ide?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a System Property while running the code.

The catch is to introduce this line in code: System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");

Or to pass it in VM option: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true